# jQuery link elements by attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have this script:

```
$('.bx').each(function () {
    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        if (this.id == $('.tester').attr("id")) {
            $('div.tester').css("display", "inline-block");
        }
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        $('.tester').css("display", "none");

    });
});
```

What I want to do is this: when I hover over some of these input fields, a hidden div should appear. On mouseout, it should hide back.

The thing works, but when i hover over input id="3", the div with id="3" should appear, not all of them sharing the same class name. Same goes with id="4" for both the input and the div. I don`t want to hardcode the ids in there because my inputs and divs are dynamically generated.

That being said, is there any way to achieve this taks?

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you in advance

**JSFiddle here:** https://jsfiddle.net/pkb3q6kq/19/

Comment: An id must be unique through a whole html document... you should work with classes!

Comment: But if the id is unique and classes are shared, how can I pinpoint each and every element?

Comment: I can't get your question.. Sorry!  But I'll try it once more:  With the ID attribute you pinpoint only ONE element. If you want group elements up  you should use the class attribute.

Comment: @WaKai It is solved. The elements i generate have unique ids are are bunched up together, like pairs of visible and invisible elements. Upon hovering the visibile elements the ones invisible show up. That was my problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hover`:

Changes in HTML:

```
<div id="message_3" class="tester">HAHAHAHAHAHAHA</div>
         ^^^^^^^^^
<div id="message_4" class="tester">Another HAHAHAHAHAHAHA</div>
         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Javascript:

```
$('.bx').hover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");

        $('#message_' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    },

    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        $('.tester').css("display", "none");
    });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pkb3q6kq/21/

1. `Id` must be **unique** on the page
2. You don't need to bind event to each element individually inside `each` loop, you can bind event using classname
3. `$(this)` inside event handler is the element on which event occured
4. You can use `hover` as combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseout`

Comment: Your fiddle still violates #1 of your listing.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much, Tushar, it is exactly the solution i was looking for! Beer`s on me!

Comment: @Tushar  but you are still presenting an invalid html code, no matter for which purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7d7r511/1/). I didn't want to change your whole code, just the minimum necessary.

In your HTML i simply added the `data-id` attributes so you can use them as unique identifiers.

```
<div id="3" data-id="3" class="tester">HAHAHAHAHAHAHA</div>
<div id="4" data-id="4" class="tester">Another HAHAHAHAHAHAHA</div>
<input type="text" id="3" class="bx" value="tanananna" />
<input type="text" id="2" class="bx" value="bla bla bla bla" />
<input type="text" id="1" class="bx" value="tanccccccccccccccccananna" />
<input type="text" id="2" class="bx" value="bla aaaaaaaaaaaaabla bla bla" />
<input type="text" id="1" class="bx" value="tanandasdasdasdasdaanna" />
<input type="text" id="4" class="bx" value="bla hahahahah bla bla" />
```

And in the javascript, you only show the 'div' which is related to the hovered element identifier. Check the code below.

```
$('.bx').each(function () {
    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        if (this.id == $('.tester').attr("id")) {
            $("div[data-id='" + this.id + "']").css("display", "inline-block");
        }
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        $('.tester').css("display", "none");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.bx').each(function () {
        $(this).mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
            if (this.id == $('.tester').attr("id")) {
                $('div #'+this.id).css("display", "inline-block");
            }
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "white");
            $('div #'+this.id).css("display", "none");

        });
    });
```